in package ggmosaic , geom_mosaic_text return nothing
In the code below, I want to add a label to the mosaic plot , but geom_mosaic_text returns nothing. Can anyone help with this?
Thanks!
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic)

df <- diamonds  %>%  
  summarise(sumx = sum(x), .by = c(cut, color))

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(cut), fill = color, weight = sumx))
geom_mosaic_text(aes(x = product(cut), fill = color, label=sumx))


You're missing a + at the end of the second line of code, ggplot(data = df) + geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(cut), fill = color,weight = sumx)) + geom_mosaic_text(aes(x = product(cut), fill = color,label=sumx)) works.

@LTyrone Thanks.   after add +, label [sumx] can't show in plot (IT's show color/cut, i want the number )

You need to add sumx as weight to mapping in geom_mosaic_text, same as in geom_mosaic, then use the weight with after_stat to label:
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(cut), fill = color, weight = sumx)) +
  geom_mosaic_text(aes(x = product(cut), fill = color, weight = sumx, label = after_stat(.wt)))


Thanks !  .wt  means weight ？I check the help file about after_stat, there is no information about .wt or other parameter

It seems to be an issue with the documentation. It supposed to be in the Computed variables section in the help for geom_* or corresponding stat_* function.
